# Is there a way to force open a new browser window from MOzilla to IE by Onclick function?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

Iam getting new window pop up by using window.open(), but need When i click button in Mozilla browser, a new pop window should open in Internet Explorer, Is it possible......

Answer (score 6):

What about non-Microsoft operating systems? Internet Explorer is not available on e.g. Linux. As such this is **not** possible. Executing arbitrary external applications *should* not be possible, at least not without the user's explicit permission. That would be a serious security risk.

Why do you want to do this? Does you website not render properly on anything other than IE? If that is so, then you may want to improve the [HTML](http://validator.w3.org/)/[CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)/Javascript to make it more standards/cross-browser compliant.

Of course, you could just *ask* or *advice* the user to view your website in IE. Not a fancy solution, but it has been done that way for ages. Firefox has the [IE Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1419) add-on, which allows users to render pages using IE's render engine inside the Firefox GUI. This makes things slightly more convenient, but it's still a manual process which requires the user's explicit consent.

---

As a side note, something akin to what you want is possible with the combination IE/[Google Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/). If you add the following meta tag in the *target* page, then IE with Google Chrome Frame installed will use Google's instead of IE's rendering engine ([source](http://blog.chromium.org/2009/09/introducing-google-chrome-frame.html)):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
```

I am not aware of any other browser/plugin combination with this feature.

Comment: `Does you website not render properly on anything other than IE?`. Please let me know if you know that kind of website :)

Answer (score 3):

No. Not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If it was possible to run other applications straight from the web, you would already have tons of malware on your computer. Of course this is impossible and not everyone has Windows.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible if you have control over clients PC (like e.g. company network). There are handlers for special urls in Firefox that allow you to open external application. It requires approval from user. I saw such links for Skype or other IM clients. And one another example is mailto: link.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are no such compatibilities in DOM, niether there's access necessary for JS to know system capabilities... but I just found this add-on, [IE View](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/35), that let's you load pages in IE with a right click (using context menu) and mark certain sites to be loaded from IE only.